# execute composer install from web request

Tags: php, composer-php, exec

I have a webhook setup in github (`deploy.php`) that calls my server every time something is merged. `deploy.php` checks that the merge went into master.  If it did then it calls `git fetch` and `git merge`.  I also want it to call `composer install --no-interaction` so that any new dependencies will be installed.  My code is doing the following:

```
exec('composer install --no-interaction', $out, $ret);
echo print_r($out,true)." $ret";
```

`$out` is just an empty array.  `$ret` = 1.

However, if I log in to the server and run:

```
sudo -Hu apache php -a

php > exec('composer install --no-interaction', $out, $ret);
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

php > echo $ret;
0
```

I have tried to get this to work in many ways.  I used `shell_exec`, `exec`, a bash script, and none of this works.  I tried using an absolute path to composer.  I checked apaches permissions to call composer and the shell script.

Please let me know if this even possible.

Comment: Have you tried adding a chdir(__DIR__); to the top of deploy.php?

Comment: How did you fix this

Comment: @3m1n3n3 I don't remember how this was fixed. It was so long ago. Sorry.